# How to get rid of the KeyError when giving an unknown name

Tags: python

I was trying to make a program that can tell the students their marks for the year but I ran into a problem if the students is not in the Dictionary.

Here is the source code:

```
def repeat():
   while people in imployees:
    print(students[input("Enter you name to see year results: ")]
continue


students ={
"JOHN": 81,
"Peter": 67,
"Herry": 100,
"Wick": 0
}

for learners in students:
   if imployees == repeat():
    print(students[input("Enter you name to see year results: ")]
```

If I run the program it work perfectly but If type a wrong user it gives me a `KeyError`. So how can I make the program restart if I give an unknown name instead of it giving a `KeyError` then it ends itself.

Comment: look into `defaultdict` .

Comment: `students['jack']` --> `student.get('jack')` . This will return None when jack is not there

Comment: 1. Add try-except block in your code to handle errors and give expected functionality in case of error. 2. For dict you should use .get() method, to get the values using keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can access valuesof a dictionary also via the .get() method, which allows you to set an additional parameter for the value to return in case the entered value was not found.

```
print(students.get(input("Enter you name to see year results: "), "Invalid entry!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some typos. You forgot to close the brackets in both of your `print` statements. Also, `repeat()` doesn't return anything, so you're basically comparing against `None`. I'm not sure what `imployees` is, so can't help you with that. You also didn't indent `continue` so that would throw some syntax errors. You should use an if statement or a try-catch. I know that slows down the program, especially in a language like Python, but it's a way.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a try-except block to handle exceptions such as the KeyError. Place the section of code within the try block and use the except block to handle it. For example:

```
try:
    print(students[input("Enter you name to see year results: ")])

except KeyError:
    print("Enter a correct name for the student")
```

I changed some of the typos in your code, such as missing close parenthesis ")" for your print statements, but the concept should still hold good wherever you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is via `try`/`except`:

```
students = {
    "JOHN": 81,
    "Peter": 67,
    "Herry": 100,
    "Wick": 0
}

while True:
    try:
        print(students[input("Enter your name to see year results: ")])
    except KeyError as err:
        print(f"No such student {err}!")
```

Another option is to test for the error condition before you access the dictionary.  This will be a more familiar pattern if you're used to languages that don't support exceptions:

students = {
"JOHN": 81,
"Peter": 67,
"Herry": 100,
"Wick": 0
}

```
while True:
    try:
        name = input("Enter your name to see year results: ")
        if name in students:
            print(students[name])
        else:
            print(f"No such student {name}!")
```

Note that with the `if` method you need to explicitly pause in your sequence of operations to check for the error condition, which is why the `input` call needs to go on its own line; with the `try` method you can just write out the entire combined statement and it will automatically jump to the `except` block when a matching exception is raised.  The `try` method is generally preferred because it lets you handle errors in more complex situations without having to sprinkle your code with conditionals.